# What sets vim history?

Tags: vim

I have had the command

```
set history=10000
```

in my .vimrc for a while, and realized that it wasn't setting the history -

```
:set history
```

prints `20`.

I then moved `set history=10000` to the end of my .vimrc and re-sourced it, and now `history=10000` as requested.

There are no other instances of `set history` in my .vimrc.  What other commands set the history length?  Is it possible that function definitions override history?  Are there other settings I should be worried about overriding?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the help,

> 'history' 'hi'        number  (**Vim default: 20**, Vi default: 0)
>
> NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
>       set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.

, so if you have `set nocompatible` somewhere in the vimrc (it is very common to have it), then `set history` must go after this statement. It is a generic rule: no matter what you write, it should go after `set nocompatible`. It *must* go after `set nocompatible` if it is an option. There are some things (including some options) that are safe to appear before it, but the only thing I use before this statement is a guard.

Comment: This may have been the reason, why I was losing my history. are there any common circumstances when your viminfo file may be reset?

Comment: @alpha_989 Nothing I know about, short of forcefully writing viminfo with `:wviminfo!` (note: without bang it will read and merge), and that should normally “reset” viminfo if `&viminfo` option is close to blank in terms of setting what data to write (or was close to blank when reading) (though not completely empty, that disables viminfo).

Comment: @alpha_989 There are also variants of switching: I am not entirely sure what Vim will do if you switch to an *older* version, but newer ones have some nice additions, and viminfo format does not have well defined forward compatibility I know about, though it does have some forward compatibility AFAIK. When switching to Neovim from Vim viminfo file while not being damaged is no longer read as format has changed - basically I added some nice features, similar to new ones Bram added to Vim some time after, but also made format binary, occupy less space and completely defined in documentation.

Answer (score 25):

Type:

```
:verbose set history
```

This will tell you from where [`'history'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27history%27) was last set.

N.B: If it says:

```
  history=20
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

...and you don't have either `set hi=20` or `set history=20` in your [.vimrc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#.vimrc), you need to ensure that you have `set history=10000` **after** [`set nocp`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27compatible%27), as highlighted by [ZyX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8932857/78845). This is *probably* why you found that it worked when you moved this to the end of your initialisation file.

Comment: `nocp` was indeed the problem.  I've accepted the other answer, but hopefully this has enough upvotes to catch peoples' attention as the 'verbose' bit is helpful.